# sorting folders in vscode doesn't consider nested files when sorting by modification date?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Let's imagine we have 2 folders with files in vscode project:

```
folder1
folder2
 folder21
  file21.txt
 file2.txt
```

so in this situation if we set up *Explorer: Sort Order* to *modified* and we modified file2.txt - then folder2 be desplayed before folder1 that is good. But, if we modified file21.txt in sub-folder (nested than) folder21 - nothing happened, folder1 still be displayed above folder2 in vscode file explorer.

So probably there's some options to fine-tune this behavior?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a setting, I'm willing to bet that it doesn't exist, and that you'll need to [raise a feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md). If you do, please ping me here with a link to your issue ticket.